# Как настроить правильно телеграмм бота с алертами

Tags: python, telegram-bot, async-await, бот, asyncio

Хотелось бы уточнить возможность асинхронной работы команд в боте и вызываемых функций по времени (алертов).

Есть функция алертилки, которая проверяет данные каждые N минут

```
async def check():
    nows = datetime.now()
    if time(10, 00, 0) <= nows.time():
       print(1)


def repeat(coro, loop):
    asyncio.ensure_future(coro(), loop=loop)
    loop.call_later(DELAY, repeat, coro, loop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.call_later(DELAY repeat, check, loop)
    executor.start_polling(dp, loop=loop)
```

Также есть возможность вызова данных через команду /print

```
@dp.message_handler(), который вызывается по команде /print

@dp.message_handler()
async def send_text(msg: types.Message):
            if '/print' in msg.text.lower():
                await bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'print')
```

Как сделать так, чтобы алертилка не мешала работе команды /print? Бывают моменты, когда функция send_text() встает в очередь и ждёт полной проверки данных в алертилке (таких алертилок в боте много). Можете подсказать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неправильно изложил вопрос - в tasks aiogram были блокирующие функции, наилучшее решение - сделать их асинхронными

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот вариант

```
from threading import Thread
def check():
    nows = datetime.now()
    if time(10, 00, 0) <= nows.time():
       print(1)

@dp.message_handler()
def send_text(msg: types.Message):
    if '/print' in msg.text.lower():
        await bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'print')

tasks=[]
tasks.append(Thread(target=check))
tasks.append(Thread(target=send_text))
for task in tasks:
    task.start()
for task in tasks:
    task.join()
```